# What is the installation structure of python on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, python, python3

So I completely broke my python. I am not really interested in fixing it, I am going to do a reinstall of my OS anyways.

This got me thinking however. How does a python install work on Linux? specifically:
How are packages installed (What's with the site-packages and dist-packages directories)?
How come that when I use sudo pip (I know I shouldn't do that) it uses a different version than the normal pip?

Those are just some things that peaked my interest however, it just seems like a magical black box to me right now.

My Linux distro is Ubuntu is that has an influence.